# WifiManager: Channel connection lost in Android 5.0.2 and reboot

Tags: android, wifi-direct, reboot, wifimanager

I'm trying to create a WiFip2p GroupOwner. In a non-specific moment in the logcat the phrase "WifiManager: Channel connection lost" appears and the device reboots. I'm working with a Nexus7 2013 with Android 5.0.2. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

me too. Auto reboot at line setWifiApEnabled.invoke(mgr, config, true); but I don't know why. Asus zenphone 5 and android ver 4.3

Comment: This is not an answer. Do you know you can comment on the original post ?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I have just join stackoverflow and have not 50 reputation so I can not add a comment in the original post.... If yes, please remove it (my answer). Many thanks!